# check checkbox addclass when table row clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table I'm wanting to check the checkbox & add a class to a div when the user clicks on the table row, I can't get it to add the class.
can anyone show me where i'm going wrong.

HTML BELOW:

```
<div class="widgit">
<table id="QR_table">
 <thead>
   <tr class="QR_table-row">
     <th class="qr_action">Checkbox</th>
     <th class="qr_action">Action</th>
     <th class="qr_from">FROM</th>
      <th class="qr_to">TO</th>
      <th class="qr_trans">Transport</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="QR-row">
        <td class="checkbox">
            <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="qr_action">PT</td>
        <td class="qr_from">4</td>
        <td class="qr_to">21</td>
        <td class="qr_trans">WC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="QR-row">
        <td class="checkbox">
            <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td class="qr_action">PT</td>
        <td class="qr_from">8</td>
        <td class="qr_to">2</td>
        <td class="qr_trans">T</td>
    </tr>        
</tbody>
```

JQUERY BLOW:

```
$(function() {
  $(".QR-row").click(function() {
    var $chk = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));
       if($($chk).is(':checked')){
        $(".widgit").addClass("modal-open");  
        } else {
          $(".widgit").removeClass("modal-open");
        }   
  });               
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Razor303/f71L1esa/)

Comment: Your code is working fine...? https://jsfiddle.net/f71L1esa/1/

Comment: but it's not adding modal-open to the div with the class of widgit...

Comment: Yes it is, if you look at my example fiddle I added the background-color to that class so you can see it being added.

Comment: Your code adds that class and working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of View everything works fine.

In your fiddle the only div that you have is around your table and it seems to be the one you try to give a class.

```
<div class="widgit">
<table id="QR_table">
```

And everything works fine. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Razor303/f71L1esa/)

If you want it to do something else then you have to be a bit more specific about what you try to achive

Comment: i'm trying to add a Refills modal when the users clicks on the table row, the Refills code has a button to trigger the addclass with a checkbox hidden Thanks I think I'm on the right bath, it does work in fiddle